# Set-Cookie for a login system

Tags: cookies, setcookie

I've run into a few problems with setting cookies, and based on the reading I've done, this should work, so I'm probably missing something important.

**This situation:**

Previously I received responses from my API and used JavaScript to save them as cookies, but then I found that using the set-cookie response header is more secure in a lot of situations.

I have 2 cookies: "nuser" (contains a username) and key (contains a session key). nuser shouldn't be httpOnly so that JavaScript can access it. Key should be httpOnly to prevent rogue scripts from stealing a user's session. Also, any request from the client to my API should contain the cookies.

*The log-in request*

Here's my current implementation: I make a request to my login api at localhost:8080/login/login (keep in mind that the web-client is hosted on localhost:80, but based on what I've read, port numbers shouldn't matter for cookies)

First the web-browser will make an OPTIONS request to confirm that all the headers are allowed. I've made sure that the server response includes access-control-allow-credentials to alert the browser that it's okay to store cookies.
[image: Header Information for the OPTIONS request]

Once it's received the OPTIONS request, the browser makes the actual POST request to the login API. It sends back the set-cookie header and everything looks good at this point.
[image: Header Information for the POST request]

*The Problems*
This set-up yields 2 problems. Firstly, though the nuser cookie is not httpOnly, I don't seem to be able to access it via JavaScript. I'm able to see nuser in my browser's cookie option menu, but document.cookie yeilds "".

Secondly, the browser seems to only place the Cookie request header in requests to the exact same API (the login API):
[image]

But, if I do a request to a different API that's still on my localhost server, the cookie header isn't present:
[image]
Oh, and this returns a 406 just because my server is currently configured to do that if the user isn't validated. I know that this should probably be 403, but the thing to focus on in this image is the fact that the "cookie" header isn't included among the request headers.

So, I've explained my implementation based on my current understanding of cookies, but I'm obviously missing something. Posting exactly what the request and response headers should look like for each task would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, still not exactly what was causing the problem with this specific case, but I updated my localhost:80 server to accept api requests, then do a subsequent request to localhost:8080 to get the proper information. Because the set-cookie header is being set by localhost:80 (the client's origin), everything worked fine. From my reading before, I thought that ports didn't matter, but apparently they do.